# Why am I seeing low transfer speed with Robocopy between two external SSDs?

Tags: ssd, powershell, backup, windows-11, robocopy

I'm using Robocopy within a PowerShell script to backup my main SSD to another SSD, but I'm having problems with the file transfer speed.

While in Windows Explorer I have writing speeds of 300~400 MB/s, in Robocopy the average is 80 MB/s.

My command line is this:

```
robocopy "$($source = $drv;$source)" "$($destination = "$dst";$destination)"  /e /MT:4 /NJH /NDL /NC /BYTES /copyall /A-:SH /xd $IgnorarPastas /xf $IgnorarArquivos /log:"$dst\_Backup Logs\$filedate-robocopylog.txt" /tee | Get-RobocopyProgress -ErrorAction 0
```

The reason I'm using Robocopy within PowerShell is because I created a script to detect the backup and destination drives automatically, this makes the process simpler and more visual.

Another point is that I use a function to have copy progress with PowerShell.

##### What I've already tried.

1. I have already tried to change the number of cores by changing the `/MT` parameter
2. I've already tried disabling the progress function to see if it was interfering. I got the same speeds.
3. I've already tried disabling the log, same speeds.

##### Considerations:

1. Both SSDs are Corsair MP600 Core.
2. The SSDs are external and are connected by Orico enclosures, one has a 40Gbps Thunderbolt interface and the other has a 20Gbps USB 3.2 Gen 2 interface.
3. One of the SSDs uses my notebook's Thunderbolt 4 interface, the other is connected to USB 3.2 Gen 1. I've already tried reversing their connection.

##### Comments

Analyzing the behavior of the SSD in the task manager, I see that the SSD that is receiving the backup has 100% usage and a high average response time, around 2000ms.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

#### Edit - Additional Information

Initially I thought it was something related to Robocopy because I don't usually copy large folders directly in Windows Explorer, so I wasn't seeing this oscillation since the copy speed remains high for about 10 seconds, which is often enough to accomplish copying the files.

Now I did in-depth tests, copying large folders to be able to analyze the Explorer copy process for longer, and the result is this in the photo:

[image]

In the graph it is possible to observe the speed oscillation, it remains for a while at around 400MB/s, oscillates, and then remains stable at around 80MB/s.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150631/discussion-on-question-by-tyrone-hirt-why-am-i-seeing-low-transfer-speed-with-ro); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: After many tests, the main cause of the low speed seems to be the /MT:4 parameter. I was able to observe that the higher this value, the greater the device's average response time (you can observe this in the task manager). Maybe higher numbers work better with devices that have DRAM, but the fact is that leaving /MT:2, I'm managing to get a constant average of 500MB/s (source SSD on Thunderbolt 3 and the backup SSD on USB 3.2 gen 1) , which is what I expected from these SSDs.